# Why is it called a "Class literal" when it functions more like an object?

Tags: java, literals

For example:

> Class c = String.class;

The above statement assigns the variable c to an object, if this is the case why do we call classname.class a "literal" when it functions like an object?

Comment: It assigns to a reference variable actually, but who says a literal can't be an object?

Answer (score 1):

A literal is a special syntax that compiler directly understands as a value, as opposed to having do produce the value using some operations. As opposed to, e.g. `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`, `String.class` does not access a property of the `String` class object - it *is* the `String` class object. You can see it in disassembly:

```
class Test {
  public static Class classProperty = Test.class;
  public static String stringProperty = "foo";

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = "bar";
    String b = Test.stringProperty;
    Class x = Test.class;
    Class y = Test.classProperty;
  }
}
```

compiles to:

```
class Test {
  public static java.lang.Class classProperty;

  public static java.lang.String stringProperty;

  Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String bar
       2: astore_1
       3: getstatic     #3                  // Field stringProperty:Ljava/lang/String;
       6: astore_2
       7: ldc           #4                  // class Test
       9: astore_3
      10: getstatic     #5                  // Field classProperty:Ljava/lang/Class;
      13: astore        4
      15: return

  static {};
    Code:
       0: ldc           #4                  // class Test
       2: putstatic     #5                  // Field classProperty:Ljava/lang/Class;
       5: ldc           #6                  // String foo
       7: putstatic     #3                  // Field stringProperty:Ljava/lang/String;
      10: return
}
```

Here, you can see that `Test.stringProperty` and `Test.classProperty` act as property accessors (using `getstatic`), while the `Test.class` and `"bar"` get treated as literals (directly loading their value using `ldc`, "load constant").

---

Finally, "literal" is not opposed to "an object", but a "non-literal" - an evaluated value. The opposite of "an object" in Java is "a primitive". The two are completely separate axes. Here are some examples:

- `1` - a primitive literal (specifically, an `int`)
- `"foo"` - an object literal (specifically, a `String`)
- `3 - 2` - a primitive non-literal (although, this is an easy case so that the compiler will pre-calculate and treat it as literal `1`)
- `"fo" + "o"` - an object non-literal (ditto, the compiler will optimise it as literal `"foo"`)
- `x + y` (assuming `x` and `y` are `int`) - a primitive non-literal (that cannot be optimised away)
- `x + y` (assuming `x` and `y` are `String`) - an object non-literal (that cannot be optimised away)

similarly

- `Test.class` - an object literal (specifically, of class `Class`)
- `new Test().getClass()` - an object non-literal (specifically, of class `Class`)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Javadoc for `java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> Class has no public constructor. Instead Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.

In addition, if you read the Javadoc, you will see that `Class` exposes no public setter mutation methods.

So instances of `Class` don't follow the usual cycle of objects of instantiation, and for the most part cannot be modified.  Therefore, `String.class` behaves more like a literal value, than a usual Java object.